# PHP date() is wrong when using a UTC timestamp

Tags: php

```
$dayBasedOnUTC = date('l', $_GET['day']);
```

Why is it that when I echo the value of `$dayBasedOnUTC` the day returned is a Tuesday?

The UTC value of `$_GET['day']` is: 1409393126144

If you put that number into any Unix Timestamp Converter you will see the date is Saturday.

Comment: What is the *actual* value of day as you pass it into date?

Comment: That timestamp *is* a Tuesday.

Comment: `strtotime($_GET['day'])`

Comment: Why when I put the value into this: http://www.epochconverter.com/ does it say that the GMT date of that timestamp is a Saturday?

Comment: @bhttoan Read the question

Comment: I googled for "Unix Timestamp Converter" - here's the link: http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm and then I pasted your timestamp, after which it spits out Tuesday, as it should. Therefore, you're obviously wrong by your own definition, no?

Comment: @N.B. Well if you read my previous comment and used the converter I put in chat (which I googled for just like you did), you will see it "spits" out different data. So clearly there was a misunderstanding, no?

Comment: You said the UTC value of day was 1409393126144 which could have meant that the value of day was a formatted date which you then converted to UTC - your question is ambiguous at best...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `1409393126144` is a *Javascript timestamp*, which is counted in *milliseconds*. PHP expects its UNIX timestamps in *seconds* though. So `1409393126144` to PHP is a timestamp in the far future.

Divide by 1000 to get the correct value:

```
echo date('l', 1409393126144 / 1000);
```